# Linux: Overwrite all files in folder with specified data?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a question, can linux overwrite all files in specified folder with data?

I have multiple files in folder:
`file1.mp4 file2.mp3, file3.sh, file4.jpg`
Both have some data (music, videos.. etc)

And I want to automatically overwrite these files with custom data (for example `dummy file`)

Comment: You question is not really clear i think. So whats the problem to overwrite the files?

Comment: I've voted to close this question because it appears to be a request for a recommendation for a tool or solution, rather than a request for assistance with your own code. This makes your question off-topic for StackOverflow. If that assessment was incorrect, and you do indeed want help writing your own code, then please [add your work so far to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46268137/edit) and I'll happily retract my close vote.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 3):

With **cat** command:

```
for f in folder/*; do cat dummyfile > "$f"; done
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `tee` 
       tee - read from standard input and write to standard output and files

```
$ echo "writing to file" > file1

$ echo "writing something else to all files" | tee file1 file2 file3

$ head *
==> file1 <==
writing something else to all files

==> file2 <==
writing something else to all files

==> file3 <==
writing something else to all files
```